# How should I level the ground for my above ground pool?

Tags: pool

In my area we get about 3.5 seasons hot enough to swim and I have a limited budget. What I have been doing is setting up an inflatable ring pool (14' x 3.5') to cool off in. The problem is my yard has a slope. My strategy is good I think. I place a board in the middle on a 2.5' bolt and try to work around with a level, digging the high areas and building the low areas and adding lots of play sand. See the images for examples.

[image: initial dig]
[image: where I am at so far this year]
[image: last years slanty-ness]

My problem is the far side (where the wall is) always compresses and the pool leans as you can see in the third image. I am constantly afraid a kid will kick against that wall after the water is high and the whole thing will just roll down the hill.

What should I do that could solve this issue for less than $100?

Comment: How much sand is under the sagging area?

Comment: more than 2 or 3 or inches. I think the thing to do is not pack with sand or dig down to dirt.

Comment: Yeah, that is too much sand.  The sand is there to provide a nice surface to feel good on the feet, not puncture the pool, not stress the liner, and protect from the ground underneath puncturing/stressing.  But too much sand takes on its own life:  it is able to move and carry the pool (at the extreme).  Depending on how coarse the ground is, only 0.5 inch to 1.5 inches should be used.  The 1.5 inches would be if there is very coarse gravel underneath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should dig down on the high side, instead of building up the low side. Or build up the low side in a more sound manner, though that will likely cost more than $100.

Comment: Digging down the high side to attain level is the direction the manufacturer provided on the poo I purchased. And sand was specifically mentioned against using.

Comment: As for 'now' option I would second Teste101's opinion to dig high side to the level You built lower one. Try to dig both sides to 'solid' lower side (so no loose soil will be under the pool.

Comment: This is my plan for next year. For this year we are swimming on shifting sand. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the sand is shifting. Like Tester said, you may need to build up the low side with something more secure, like using those landscaping blocks with a bottom layer that is at least half in the ground. Then backfilling with dirt and compacting it.

Answer (score 2):

I used yellow sand for my foundation. It's a mix of sand and clay. I filled the whole form and located where my pool will be. Leveled the best i could( I did good). pick out the hard clumps and just put a little sand in my circumference for softness. Now I'll put my liner down. Set up my pool. As it fills i will walk the perimeter to check for any spots i dont like before it gets to full. Then I'll take my silica sand and surround the outer side of pool for some added support. Its just a 10x30.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.